# IF function in jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying to run an overflow check if I hover on a div. But I use jQuery for the hover function and in the next function there's just simple Javascript. It's not working because I assume one can't use the if then function inside a jQuery function... but then I need the action that if I hover over the div the if then function should be executed. Can someone help me please? =)

So it's jQuery (hover) -> JS (check overflow) -> jQuery (add to div (here: "...read more..."))

HTML:

```
<div class="hover_cap">
<div class="hcd">
Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum 
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hover_cap {
   width:150px;
   max-height: 17.5ex;
   border: 1px solid red;
}

.hcd {
    line-height:2.5ex;
    max-height:12.5ex;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.readmore {
  padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.hover_cap').hover(

  if (function checkOverflow(hcd) {
      var curOverflow = hcd.style.overflow;

      if (!curOverflow || curOverflow === "hidden") hcd.style.overflow = "visible";

      var isOverflowing = hcd.clientWidth < hcd.scrollWidth || hcd.clientHeight < hcd.scrollHeight;

      hcd.style.overflow = curOverflow;

      return isOverflowing;
    }) {

    function() {
      $(this).append($('<a>...read more...</a>'));
    },
    function() {
      $(this).find("a:last").remove();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure, you are asking that the hover function should work only if isOverflowing is true?

Comment: Read about callbacks in javascript.
In your checkOverflow function pass your callbacks, if isOverflowing is true execute according to what you want to do.
Read the part 'Basic Principles when Implementing Callback Functions'.

http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/

Comment: @er-han no it's the other way around. The text should be added when isOverflowing is true and overflow should be checken if I hover over the div =)

Comment: It must be `if (checkOverflow(hcd))`. `checkOverflow()` must be defined somewhere.

Comment: By the way, you should make the post's title more clear and specific to the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a snippet for you:
When you hover the outer div, if the inner div's text is overflowed append a 'readmore' button to the outer div.
When you unhover the outer div, if there is an appended 'readmore' button remove it.

```js
function isOverflowed(element){
    return element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight || element.scrollWidth > element.clientWidth;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.hover_cap').hover(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $textContainer = $this.find('.hcd');
    $textContainer.css('overflow','auto');
    var isOverflowing = isOverflowed($textContainer[0]);
     $textContainer.css('overflow','hidden');
    if(isOverflowing) {
      $this.append($('<a>...read more...</a>'));
    }
  }, function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var lastA = $this.find("a:last");
    if(lastA) {
      lastA.remove();
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.hover_cap {
   width:150px;
   max-height: 17.5ex;
   border: 1px solid red;
}

.hcd {
    line-height:2.5ex;
    max-height:12.5ex;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.readmore {
  padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hover_cap">
<div class="hcd">
Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum 
</div>
</div>

<br/>
<br/>

<div class="hover_cap">
<div class="hcd">
Short text, no overflow
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh thanks for the detailed answer ^^ Actually I want that overflow still stays hidden, but I think it will be no problem for me to change the code :) Thanks a lot ^_^

Comment: @DidiKong sorry, my mistake. I had understood false. Now i fixed the snippet. The overflow is always hidden. You are welcome, by the way :)

Comment: Wow, thanks to you I finally got the result I wanted after trying to adjust the code you posted =D